# Jenkins C++ build chain

Tags: c++, jenkins, gcc

I'm on a c++ project and i have to set-up the jenkins slave. My project have 3 different directory (building scripts, Mylibrary, MyApplication), every directory is a git repository.

```
node {
stage ('Checkout'){
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: '*/devel_dimant']], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
        relativeTargetDir: 'build_scripts']], 
    submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'file:///home/antonio/Projects/Azalea/rc_octo_cmn_build']]
    ])
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: '*/devel_dimant']], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
        relativeTargetDir: 'liboctopus']], 
    submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'file:///home/antonio/Projects/Azalea/rc_octo_cmn_core']]
    ])
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: '*/devel_dimant']], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
        relativeTargetDir: 'gateway_daemon']], 
    submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'file:///home/antonio/Projects/Azalea/rc_gtw_octogtwd']]
    ])    
}
stage ('Build liboctopus'){
    dir("liboctopus"){
        sh ('./../build_scripts/octo_build.sh')

    }
    dir('liboctopus/release/HOST'){
        sh('ls')
    }
}
stage ('Build gateway_daemon'){
    dir("gateway_daemon"){
        sh ('./../build_scripts/octo_build.sh')
    }
}
```

This is my pipeline, when i try to compile Myapplication in stage Build daemon, gcc fails:

> > Building application 'release/HOST/octogtwd', version == '0.0.1', build config == 'release'
> >     g++ -o release/HOST/octogtwd release/HOST/configuration_handler.opp release/HOST/gtw_logger.opp release/HOST/main.opp -Wl,-rpath=/opt/OctopusIoT/lib -pthread -rdynamic -Wl,-pie -L../liboctopus/release/HOST -lrt -lpthread -lsystemd -loctopus -ljson-c
> >     /usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -loctopus
> >     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> >     make: *** [Makefile:74: release/HOST/octogtwd] Error 1

I've created the symlink to the library in the jenkins directory:

```
liboctopus-0.1.0.a
liboctopus.so
liboctopus.so.0
liboctopus.so.0.1.0
```

The project compile on the HOST machine (relative path work). Not on jenkins.

Comment: "mylib" isn't mentioned even once in the provided example. Please present a [MCVE] as best you can

Comment: Do you mean `-lmylib`? Are you sure about the paths? what are the logs? [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need to split your Job into 3 Jobs (building scripts, Mylibrary, MyApplication), and use the [copy-artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to copy the artifact from one job to another.
Example:

```
node {
   // setup env..
   // copy the deployment unit from another Job...
   step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
          projectName: 'webapp_build',
          filter: 'target/orders.war']);
   // deploy 'target/orders.war' to an app host
}
```

I found this [link](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/copying-artifacts-between-builds-jenkins-workflow).

Comment: I can't split, the Projects directories link eachother, i can't modify the structure. I think the problem is the non-visibility between the diffrent repo

Comment: Then you can create a folder (Example: ./commons) and put the compiled artifacts in this folder. And put references to this folder.